# Use Response.Write() to Create Buttons in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create an `<asp:Button>` in ASP.Net. I have the following code right now:

```
              <b>Tags:
               <%
                   List<string> tags = GetTags();
                   foreach(string tag in tags)
                   {
                       Response.Write(tag + " ");
                   }
               %>
            <br/>
```

However, all this does is print the text to the web page. Can I modify this statement in someway to allow me to create buttons with it? Or am I stuck with just text?

Comment: You can't create an `<asp:Button>` in this fashion. Please elaborate on what your `List<BrainStorm.Tags>` is and what result you wish to see.

Comment: I updated the post to make it simpler. Its just a a string that is the name of the tag. I want the button to use this for its `Text` property.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create server-side controls in this manner. Simply declare the control in your markup as you would normally do with any html element. For example:

```
<asp:button id="btnSubmitForm" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" />
```

If what you want is create simple tags on your markup; do something like this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="tagPlaceHolder" runat="Server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

And on the server-side:

```
List<BrainStorm.Tags> tags = BrainStorm.PostRunner.GetTagsForPost((long)Double.Parse(hiddenField.Value));
foreach(BrainStorm.Tags tag in tags)
{
   Button b = new Button();
   b.Text=tag.Title;
   tagPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

This will add a button for every tag you have inside your `ContentPlaceHolder`

**UPDATE:**

Inside a repeater...

```
protected void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
  {
     ContentPlaceHolder placeHolder =  ((ContentPlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("tagPlaceHolder"));


  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response. I am trying this out now. Another dumb question. This is running from inside a repeater. I cant seem to access the `tagPlaceHolder` control from inside my for loop. Any idea how to do so?